# SQL OPENQUERY, Incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I have this sql query:

```
DECLARE  @VAR varchar(8)
SET  @VAR = '20140202'
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([NMD],'SELECT * FROM NmdItemGroups01.dbo.InvTranDtl WHERE TranDate = ''' + @VAR + '''')
```

But when I run it, it gives this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '+'
```

Comment: `OPENQUERY()` does not support expression in the parameter. You will need to use `Dynamic SQL` if you need to do that

Comment: But how the queries in this link work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query

Comment: The sample uses dynamic sql.

Comment: `exec()` is `dynamic sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sp_executesql example:

```
DECLARE  @VAR varchar(8)
SET  @VAR = '20140202'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT * FROM NmdItemGroups01.dbo.InvTranDtl WHERE TranDate = @TranDate', 
    N'@TranDate DATE', 
    @VAR
```

Comment: it is indeed `Dynamic SQL`